# WooCommerce: Fire action after shipping zone is changed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a shop, which picks up shoes from the customer, cleans them and then returns them back to the customer.

It features local pickup only in an assigned area, based on a range of postcodes. But if the user types in a postcode that is not included, the site should show a message that the user is not within this area and needs to send the shoes via mail.

My question is whether there is a PHP or JavaScript hook I can catch when the user changes his postcode, so I can display this message.

I already tried to do this based on input change and to look if the ID of the shipping method is existing. But this does not quite work.

```
$('#billing_postcode').on('change', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  if ($('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup2')) {
    console.log('Pickup is possible')
  } else {
    console.log('Pickup is not possible')
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful to describe "this does not quite work" in a bit more detail as now it's not clear what you're experiencing that isn't ideal.

Comment: Hello. In this case it does not seem to be able to really find out if the ID is existing or not. It always renders the if-block, even if the ID is not existing. I guess the reason is that i looks too early for the element. Because of that it would be nice to hook into the woocommerce action that is responsible for the shipping methods. This seems to be happening with Ajax. When you enter a new postcode the order summary gets updated and show the new possible shipping methods and after this has happend I wanna display the message, as mentioned in my question.